# How to fix my code to return a pointer to a struct from a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm learning pointers and struct now and I'm a bit confused. Particularly, I want to make a function which returns a pointer to a struct. My code is compiling, but it isn't working. After I type the number of students, it asks for name and age (without reading name), and after I type the age, it closes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct details
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
};

struct details * details_pointer(int n)
{
    struct details pointer_x[n];
    struct details *pointer = pointer_x;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Student %d:\n", i);
        printf("name:\n");
        fgets(pointer[i].name, 100, stdin);
        printf("age:\n");
        scanf("%d", pointer[i]. age);
    }
    return pointer;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Type the number of persons:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct details *student = details_pointer(n);
    printf("\nName: %s\n", (*student).name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", (*student).age);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `pointer_x`'s lifetime ends when the functions exists. So whatever you return is invalid. If you want to return a pointer you have to allocate memory on the heap which you do with `malloc`. Objects created with `malloc` have to be managed manually. This is done with `free`.
Also you say `which returns a pointer to a function` - don't you mean a pointer to an object?

Comment: Thanks! It should mean "which returns a pointer to a struct". I'm going to edit it. As for the malloc, that's actually what the exercise asks (dinamic allocation), but I thought that creating a vector and attributing it to a pointer was the same thing as doing dynamic allocation, and I was indeed trying to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if the assignment requires dynamic allocation, then that's what we have to do.

Just specifying an array implicitly allocates the space while the function is running, but it disappears when the function returns. You'll need to allocate it specifically.

Revisiting your code:

```
struct details *details_pointer(int n)
{
    struct details *students = (struct details *)malloc(n * sizeof(struct details));

    .... do stuff with students[0] and the like

    return students;
}
```

This uses the `malloc()` - memory allocate - library function to get you some space, and it remains valid until you release it. The number of bytes is how many things you want (`n`) times how many bytes in *one thing* (`sizeof(struct details)`)

Later:

```
int main()
{
    struct details *student = details_pointer(n);
    .. do stuff

    free(student);
}
```

This now *uses* that memory, and releases it back to the OS when you're done.

Comment: Keep in mind that the main goal is to insure that you've allocated some memory to work with, you can either do it dynamically (with `malloc`) in the callee or allocate it in the caller.  Each has its advantages.

Comment: Thanks. I've made these adjustments. The problem with reading the name persists, though. It only asks and prints the age. Nothing appears in front of the name.

Comment: @francescobfc - I can't tell what it's doing from here, but my guess is that you're running into subtleties with `scanf()` and how it consumes whitespace.  When it prompts for the age, it's going to consume the digits, leaving the newline (the RETURN key) still in the input buffer. Then, when `fgets()` is called to read the name, it consumes that final newline - and nothing else! - giving you a blank name without pausing for it.

Comment: @francescobfc - personally I never ever ever use `scanf()` because of these whitespace problems. There are certainly ways around it, and others may weigh in, but I always read a whole line of input with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` - note the *two* `s` characters - to scan from the line I just read. This avoids many of the whitespace issues that get in the way of many.

Comment: I'm going to give a look at these. As for reading the string, scanf is working, although gets and fgets don't. I've put my code here, if you could give a look: https://pastebin.com/xMMtiDNZ

Comment: This looks reasonable, though perhaps you want a newline after the name: otherwise it prints "Name: SteveAge: 57".

Comment: But it only works with scanf, so I can't read phrases. fgets and gets aren't working.

Comment: Solving this input problem is beyond what we're likely to accomplish in the comments section of your question: perhaps open a new one? Personally I believe that `scanf()` is evil and nobody should ever use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and for the help! If you're interested in continuing the discussion, I've created a new topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685357/how-to-fix-my-code-to-read-a-string-in-a-function-that-returns-a-pointer-to-a-st

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're returning a structure variable (`pointer_x`) that's allocated locally on the stack of the inner `details_pointer()` function, but this memory is no longer reserved for you once it returns. This means you get (at best) garbage.

You have to *either* allocate memory in the function and return it (and remember to free it!) or pass the data to the function to fill it in.

```
void get_details(int n, struct details p[n])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    // do stuff with p[i]
  }
}

int main()
{
   ...
   scanf("%d", &n);
   struct details students[n];
   get_details(n, students);

   printf("\nName: %s\n", students[0].name);
   ...
}
```

I generally prefer passing data *to* the function when possible just because it simplifies memory management.

EDIT: Two notes about your existing `details_pointer()` function.

1) In `fgets(pointer[i].name, 100, stdin)`, it's a good practice to derive the number of bytes from the size of the array if it's known; in this case it is, so recommend `fgets(pointer[i].name, sizeof(pointer[i].name), stdin)`. Yours is not incorrect, but it's easier to maintain should the sizes change in the future.

2) the `scanf("%d", pointer[i].age)` needs to take the *address of* the `.age` to stuff its value in there; you're passing a number instead of an address, which is for sure incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you clarify me another thing?1) The exercise I was trying to make asks " Create a struct called details, and store into it name and age of a person. Now, write a function that receives a positive integer n and returns a pointer to a vector of size n, dinamically aloccated, of this structure. Ask for the user to type the data of this struct inside this function." How can I do this if I can't create memory inside the function?

Comment: 2) As for the point 2) you've made, isn't pointer[i].age the address, and *pointer[i].age the number?

Comment: A third point. As Phillip has pointed it out, it should work it malloc. I haven't tried it yet, but I was understanding that                                                                                                                        int *p = malloc (5*sizeof(int))           is the same as                                                                          int *x[5]                                                                                                                             int *p = x                        That's why I was doing that way

Comment: Since `pointer[i]` actually refers to a single structure member, then `pointer[i].age` refers to the numeric value of age (such as 3 or 57 or whatever).  You need to use `&` to take the address of this integer variable so `scanf()` knows where to put the result.