# How to fix my code to read a string in a function that returns a pointer to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm writing a code that uses a function to return a pointer to a struct, which is allocated dynamically. However, my code isn't reading strings. When I run it, it simply jumps the "Type name" part, I type the age, and it prints the age and nothing for the name. Strangely, the code works when I use scanf to read the string, but it didn't with gets or fgets. Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct details
{
    char name[100];
    int age;
};

struct details * details_pointer(int n)
{
    struct details *pointer = (struct details *) malloc (n*sizeof(struct details));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Student %d:\n", i);
        printf("name:\n");
        scanf("%s", pointer[i].name);
        //gets(pointer[i].name); not working
        //fgets(pointer[i].name, 100, stdin); not working
        printf("age:\n");
        scanf("%d", &pointer[i]. age);
    }
    return pointer;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Type the number of persons:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct details *student = details_pointer(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nName: %s", (*(student+i)).name);
        printf("Age: %d\n", (*(student+i)).age);
    }
    free(student);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `scanf` leaves a newline in the input stream. `fgets` gets it as the name when it is called. To prove this, change:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

to something like:

```
n = 1;
```

and you will see no problem.

If you don't want to use `scanf`, you can call `fgets` then `atoi/strtol`.

```
char    *num;
fgets(num, 100, stdin);
n = atoi(num);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way that I can continue to use scanf avoiding this problem, though?

Comment: You'd do well to avoid using `scanf()` entirely because this newline thing will bite you every other time you try to solve a problem. If you're asking the user for input, better to read a full line (with `gets()` or `fgets()`) and then use `sscanf()` to pull data from the line you just read into whatever form you need it in.  This way you are SURE that you read exactly one line at a time, and you pull all your interesting data from it, and no one read will confuse the next read.